# Batch file: command TYPE path

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make something that combines CSS files but some of them are in sub folders of the directory of the .bat file for example my structure is this 
folder ->
       css ->
            css files
       .bat file how would I do this so i don't have to put a drive on there incase I change what drive it is on

edit:

```
type lib/css/header.css >> stylesheet.css
type lib/css/footer.css >> stylesheet.css
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use relative paths?

```
type css\a.css >> output.css
type css\b.css >> output.css
REM etc...
```

Comment: @user3120013 Perhaps if you can be a bit (ok, a lot) more specific I can help.

Comment: What I want to do is have the batch file in the main directory and then when I run the batch file it'll get the css files from the folder and combine them into one with out having to but a drive label in the path if that makes sense, I'll add an example of something I made but didn't work

Comment: @user3120013 As far as I can see that description fits my answer perfectly. I don't understand the difference, or what you mean by "doesn't seem to work for me."

Comment: @user3120013 Did you type it wrong? There's nothing wrong with it, I assure you.

Comment: @user3120013 You typed `1>>` and not `>>`. Try again.

Comment: I didn't I put >> there isn't a one there

Comment: @user3120013 Are you messing with me?? Look at your own screen shot, it clearly shows `1>>`.

Comment: @user3120013 Then you're not running what you think you're running, or something. Type it out in a command prompt and see for yourself. I'm sorry, but I don't have time to help any further. Good luck.

Comment: @dvnrrs The `1` is something cmd adds on the console when redirecting stdout streams

Answer (score 0):

```
break>output.txt
for /r /d %%a in (.) do (
  type "%%~fda\*.css" >>output.txt 2>nul
)
```

Comment: Could you explain what all of this is and does please.

Comment: `for /r /d` traverse all sub directories which are accessible with `%%a` token.`type *.css` will type all css files.`2>nul` will truncate file names and the errors if dir is empty. You can remove `2>nul` if you want to display the file names in the console.

Answer (score 0):

This is simpler and recursively appends every .css file in the current directory tree into output.txt

```
@echo off
for /r %%a in (*.css) do type "%%a" >>output.txt
```